# "Face squarely" (in a straightforward manner) and "carrément"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, adverbes

> We must squarely face the issue.
>
> Nous devons carrément faire face au problème.

Can the adverb carrément convey "in a straightforward manner"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le registre n'est pas le bon, *carrément* est plutôt du domaine du français parlé où il signifie *vraiment*, ***directement***, *exactement* ou *complètement*, incluant donc celui de ***straightforward*** manner.

De même, ***squarely***, construit à partir de ***square*** exactement comme ***carrément*** l'est de ***carré***, peut avoir plusieurs sens en anglais.

Puisque celui attendu, précisé dans la question, n'est pas *honnêtement*, j'écrirais:

> Nous devons directement faire face au problème.

Une expression idiomatique pourrait aussi être:

> On ne doit pas tourner autour du pot mais affronter directement le problème.

Si le problème est ensuite rapidement résolu, on pourra alors parler d'une victoire ***rondement*** menée...

Comment: Sur la proximité très possible entre *straightforward* et *honest*: [un exemple parlant](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-merits-if-any-of-being-honest-and-straightforward-in-todays-world)

Answer (score 4):

Les traductions proposées par [jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32561/13100) sont correctes, spécialement celle avec l’ajout de *ne pas tourner autour du pot*, qui est excellente.

Il y a bien sûr d’autres possibilités, la traduction est un art quasi-inépuisable. En voici une autre possible :

- Il faut/faudra attaquer le problème de front.

Quant à la phrase proposée avec ***carrément*** (Nous devons carrément faire face au problème), elle signifierait<sup>1</sup> quelque chose comme *« Disons les choses comme elles sont : nous ne passerons pas à côté, nous devons faire face au problème »*. Pas si loin, mais pas non plus une traduction exactement fidèle de la phrase anglaise.

---

À la lecture du Merriam-Webster à [*SQUARELY*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squarely), on trouve ceci :

> In a **straightforward**<sup>2</sup> or **honest** manner. *We must squarely face the issue*.

Il me semble que cette définition se rapproche davantage de *rendre à César ce qui appartient à César*, en ce sens qu’elle propose plus de faire une évaluation juste des tenants et aboutissants du problème et de ne pas commettre l’erreur de le sous-estimer ou de l’apprécier incorrectement, que de l’attitude à adopter pour remédier au problème.

En ce sens, je proposerais :

- Il faut regarder le problème en face.

L’affirmation précédente recommande, comme le fait le Merriam-Webster, d’éviter les faux-fuyants et les biais, et d’analyser le problème objectivement afin de bien cerner sa nature.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>À la lecture de la réponse liée au début de ma réponse, je n’étais pas certain si les analyses de ce mot étaient les mêmes en Europe et au Québec. Un commentaire, ci-dessous, de [Laurent S.](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/2146/), de Belgique si je ne m’abuse, semble confirmer que les interprétations seront les mêmes de part et d’autre de l’Atlantique.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>[STRAIGHTFORWARD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straightforward), toujours selon le Merriam-Webster, peut vouloir dire *« DIRECT »*, d’où une première thématique de propositions, ci-dessus en cette réponse, mais aussi dans celle liée en son introduction *(attaquer de front, s’attaquer directement à)*. Mais encore selon la même source, on peu lire qu’il signifie aussi *« [CANDID](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candid) »*. Ce dernier mot sous-entend bel et bien l’honnêteté, et il convient donc de ne pas balayer purement et simplement cette notion sous prétexte que le mot *« HONEST »* n’a pas été utilisé dans la question.</sub>

Comment: A ma connaissance, la compréhension européenne du "carrément" correspond à celle énoncée ici. J'upvote cette réponse car je trouve que "attaquer de front" correspond assez bien au sens de "squarely face the issue" (de front = de face)

Comment: Merci, j'édite avec ajout de votre remarque.

Comment: @LaurentS. Je me suis peut-être mal exprimé mais je n'ai pas voulu dire que *carrément* ne correspondait, pas plus ou moins, à *squarely*, d'autant plus qu'un *square*, c'est carrément la même chose qu'un *carré*... Mon propos était seulement de dire que *carrément* ne collait pas avec le registre de la phrase.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est moi qui n'était pas certain. J'ai donc mis mon interprétation, en émettant mes réserves quant à la compréhension des Européens de la même phrase. Laurent S. a simplement confirmé que nos interprétations étaient assez similaires pour croire que nous comprenons la même chose en Amérique et en Europe.